# Is this definition of a Gaussian distribution correct?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, gaussian-integral

Is it correct to say for the following:
$$u_{k}\sim N(0,\gamma ^{2})$$

that "$u_{k}$ follows the Gaussian distribution with a mean of zero and a covariance of $\gamma ^{2}$" ?

I am a bit sceptical regarding the term covariance. Shouldn't that be variance?

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct. Covariance makes no sense here:

There are no two random variables $X,Y$ given, and covariance measures $E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$ which depends on how one multiplies two random variables $X,Y$ (thus covariance cannot be calculated with distributions of the random variables alone).

---

Correct would be: $\mu_k$ follows a Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\gamma^2$.

Comment: ? The covariance is weird, but it can make sense. After all, the variance of $X$ is merely the covariance of $X$ with itself. I also cannot make sense of your second paragraph, "which depends on how one multiplies two random variables"

Comment: In that case, you get $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$, which is just the variance. But yeah, this is the only sensible interpretation, I would say. And I mean that if you have given two random variables $X,Y$, you cannot calculate the covariance of $X,Y$ from their distributions alone. You also need to know what the expectation $E[XY]$ is, which depends on how these two variables 'interact'. That's what I meant with that line.